# ACPI BIOS Error

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, acpi

I am wanting to install Ubuntu-desktop onto my laptop. I has windows, switched to ubuntu-desktop, then ubuntu-server, and now trying to go back to ubuntu-desktop. I grabbed my flash drive used Rufus and ubuntu 18.04 to create a bootable USB stick like instructed, but I think something got messed up on my computer and I can't get anything to work. I've read through other answers concerning the ACPI BIOS error, but haven't been able to find the pages people are refereeing to.

I can boot up and press `shift` to get this page:

```
Install ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disc for defects
```

I can press `e` to enter this page which seems to be the page where you turn off ACPI, but I haven't been able to find that line of code or where to add it.

```
setparams `Try Ubentu without installing`
        
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux        /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/pressed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
        linitrd       /casper/initrd
```

If I either boot from the page above or try installing ubuntu with the USB that I am using, the purple ubuntu page will load for a few minutes and then I receive this page:

```
[  12.248188] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.PEGO._PRT.AR02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)

[  12.248208] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB._PICO.PEGO._PRT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psargs-531)

[  12.248550] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.PEGO._PRT.AR02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)

[  12.248561] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB._PICO.PEGO._PRT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psargs-531)

[  12.248742] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.PEGO._PRT.AR02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)

[  12.248749] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB._PICO.PEGO._PRT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psargs-531)

[  12.397888] nouveau 0000:01:00.0 bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 022554 [ IBUS ]
[  12.408638] nouveau 0000:01:00.0 bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 10AC08 [ IBUS ]

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

If there is any other information that anyone needs, please let me know!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190764/)

Comment: @karel I apologize, I no longer remember what my problem was exactly. Should I vote to close it? I wont be able to troubleshoot or give any meaningful feedback :/

Comment: If the above link answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think rufus has been stating these days that there are missing files. I had to reinstall from popos ==> moved to ubuntu, since I figured out I have to live boot in order to change root password. Don't play with groups :D.
Try to fry the USB once again, but with 20.04 trust me, also update rufus there might be some bug swimming around.

Comment: Sorry I am not following your logic here (excuse my ignorance). How do I fry my USB? Don't use rufus, use popos? And use 20.04?

Comment: By fry what I mean make a bootable USB ,apologies for my dirty slang. What I mean in there friend is that rufus has some troubles. I do not make anymore bootables via it, look forward an alternative.

Comment: I decided to use a different stick because I believe my other USBs format got all jacked up. I was able to put windows on it, which is what I wanted to do originally.